# Youtube Data API listing channel members

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

According to youtube API docs, I need a special permission to list all the sponsors on my channel.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/members/list

But I cannot fulfill this form because I have restricted access (I am logged in on the account which have created app and client which I using) and I can't even view that [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1ZdaHwMaIjZWtN28_NGckkbk_-Ca3vEOINbV_qBW-m_s/formrestricted?edit_requested=true).
How to contact youtube-developer team to ask them for unblocking this feature?
Anyone can help? 
Thanks.

Comment: same here. and the old sponsors api is dead too.

Comment: Hi, were you able to access the members.list api?

Answer (score 1):

By the [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153676482), They fix the [link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScyxqhG64jERt79bfabMdlCQqyONrlVUtJWNgPqDS8oQ-LSXA/viewform?edit_requested=true) now.